# Changing the bucket size in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-filestore

I am currently using google Filestore, and after setting up a bucket and using it for a while, I found out that the initial size of the bucket is too small for my needs.

After looking carefully at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/), I could not find how to do this. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

By bucket I understand that you are referring to the Filestore instance as the Cloud Storage Buckets do not have a fixed size, in order to increase the Filestore instance size you should follow this steps as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/editing-instances):

1. Go to the Cloud Filestore instances page.
2. Click the instance ID of the instance you want to edit.
3. On the Instance details page, click Edit.
4. Modify the instance's fileshare capacity.
5. Click Save.